# translate3d with a transition not being accelerated (being blocked by JS)

Tags: css-transitions, css-transforms, acceleration, translate3d

I am trying to animate a (100% width) div offscreen by moving it using translate3d(100%,0,0) with a 1s transition. I believe the animation should be fully offloaded to the GPU and not affected by JS, but it is freezing as I do JS computations.

Note that it doesn't freeze when I use a pixel value, e.g. translate3d(500px,0,0)

See this in effect: http://jsfiddle.net/khufzte9/

This is the code I'm using:

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#blue {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='blue'></div>
```

JS:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var blue = document.querySelector('#blue');

    blue.style.transform = 'translate3d(100%,0,0)';
    // Do some blocking work after the animation starts
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            var j = 5/3;
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated!